# how to find out my primer color

Tags: drywall, primer

I have some scratches on the drywall which was primer'ed dry wall from moving furniture. I'd like to just apply a coat of primer on the spots where the scratches are. I don't plan on painting just yet.

I bought white drywall primer, however, it doesn't exactly match the color of the primer already applied on the wall. The primer I bought is too white compared to the old one.

Is there a way to get a drywall primer with exactly the same color as the one on my current dry wall? I don't have any record of the "color code" that's already been applied...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually primer is white. In some cases the primer might be tinted. This is usually done when changing drastically from light to dark or vise versa but the color of the primer is not intended to be the final color, this is what the paint is for. When it is tinted, it would be tinted to closely match the final color.

If you want to color match, take a chip of paint to your local paint store and depending on the age, they can usually match it pretty well. I'd advise just using white primer and then getting the final paint color matched properly.

Comment: Note that the [OP doesn't intend to paint](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/21705/which-primer-to-use-on-an-old-drywall#comment31021_21706), so this is truly about color-matching the primer.